# Switch out audio and video

Tags: ffmpeg

I downloaded a movie in beautiful HD. Unfortunately, the sound is broken. I then downloaded a different copy in low res, but with an intact soundtrack. How can I use ffmpeg to take the sound from the latter and combine it with the video from the former?

I do not know what details about the files to put here, please let me know which commands I should post the output of. All I know is the first one's an `mkv` and the second's an `avi`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`-map`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) to choose which streams you want, then use `-c copy` to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux).

This example will copy the video stream(s) from `hd.mkv` and the audio stream(s) from `sd.avi`:

```
ffmpeg -i hd.mkv -i sd.avi -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -shortest output.mkv
```

If you want to offset one of the inputs see the `-itsoffset` option.